# Sort datetime data by time only

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel document with hourly energy consumption. They are listed in order but I am trying to group them by each hour. Right now it looks like

```
5/1/17 0:00
5/1/17 1:00
5/1/17 2:00
5/1/17 3:00
5/1/17 4:00
5/1/17 5:00
5/1/17 6:00
5/1/17 7:00
5/1/17 8:00
5/1/17 9:00
```

But I want it to look like

```
5/1/17 0:00
5/2/17 0:00
5/3/17 0:00
5/4/17 0:00
5/5/17 0:00
5/6/17 0:00
5/7/17 0:00
5/8/17 0:00
5/9/17 0:00
5/10/17 0:00
```

[image: Screenshot of my excel]

Comment: probably you could use some function (I am on vacation so no access to excel), another option could be that you duplicate the date/time column and the set one to be date and the second to be time, and then you can sort them by time column + date column.

Comment: Your Title & Query are contradicting each other. You have written to Sort them by Time, other is you wanna group them!! And how could you group them since Time are Unique values? Your dates are already in two groups !!

Comment: ,, Cont. your second screen shot shows Dates have unique list but time is 00:00 ??

Answer (score 0):

The following formula:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(VALUE(A2),0)
```

Displayed as `m/d/yy h:mm`

Should do what you want